# Exotic option pricing

Tags: options, option-pricing, exotics

I'm trying to price an option with payoff $\max\{a\cdot S_t - K,0\}$ where $a$ is a known constant.  Ideally I'm looking for a closed form, continuous-time solution.  Where should I begin?

Comment: This is not exotic at all. Why don't you just bring $a$ out of the max?

Comment: because I was too tired to realize I could, I suppose. thanks, now it looks quite trivial, actually. if you post it as an answer, I'll mark it accepted!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The payoff $\max\{a\cdot S_t - K,0\}$ can be re-written as $a\cdot\max\{S_t - K/a,0\}$. Therefore it can be priced as a regular call option with the strike $K/a$.